# Customize (to decrease the height of the wingpanel) in Freya

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, themes

I'm looking to see if I can reduce the height of the wingpanel in elementary OS Freya. I mean make the wingpanel smaller like normal wingpanel in elementary OS Luna.

Answer (score 10):

You can make the panel shorter by editing your system's stylesheet. If you haven't modified your system, the file you want to edit is `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css`. You can adjust the height of the panel by reducing the padding in the selector `.composited-indicator`. The current version of the stylesheet doesn't style `.composited-indicator` directly, so you'll have to add a line for it.

`.composited-indicator` is a Gtk.MenuItem so it inherits all the style properties defined in `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css` under the selector `.menu .menuitem`