# Is it possible to decrease the vertical size of wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel

I want to decrease few vertical pixels from wingpanel on Freya. Is it possible? if so, how?

Comment: AFAIK this is only possible by manually editing source code, something we generally discourage since it will likely break related items. For instance you may find icons cannot render if they do not have enough height.

Comment: I found this guide here on stackexchange https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/customize-to-decrease-the-height-of-the-wingpanel-in-freya?sgp=2 But I'm scared to try it out.

Comment: Generally that shouldn't be particularly likely to break things, and should be quite easy to revert.